# How to imitate the math environments in Libretexts math site?

Tags: tcolorbox, tikz-styles, mdframed

I found the following math environments on the [Libretexts mathematics](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Supplemental_Modules_(Analysis)/Ordinary_Differential_Equations/6%3A_Power_Series_and_Laplace_Transforms/6.6%3A_The_Laplace_Transform) site. I want to imitate these styles and structures in latex using `mdframed` and `tcolorbox` packages.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% Define a new environment for LibreTexts-style math
\newtcolorbox{libremath}[1][]{
    colframe=blue!30,
    colback=white,
    rounded corners,
    title={#1},
    attach title to upper,
    coltitle=blue!70,
    boxed title style={
        colframe=blue!30,
        colback=white,
        outer arc=0pt,
    },
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    before upper={\parindent0pt},
    after=\par\smallskip,
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{libremath}[]
        \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}
        Solve the equation for $x$:
        \[ ax^2 + bx + c = 0 \]
    \end{libremath}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something to start with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

% Define a new environment for LibreTexts-style math
\newtcolorbox{libremath}[2][]{
    enhanced,
    colframe=green!30!black,
    colback=green!20,
    sharp corners,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight},
    title={\faCubes~#2},
    toprule=0pt, rightrule=0pt,bottomrule=0pt,
    coltitle=white,
    colbacktitle=green!30!black,
    boxed title style={
        sharp corners,
    },
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    #1
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{libremath}{some title}
        \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}
        Solve the equation for $x$:
        \[ ax^2 + bx + c = 0 \]
    \end{libremath}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

As all boxes follow a similar design, they can be constructed with a common style but particular colors and names. What follows is the definition of every kind of box with it's particular color, icon and name.

Definitions and theorems use a `newtcbtheorem` definition and they will have two mandatory parameters, the theorem title and the suffix for labels. Both can be declared empty but they must appear.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

% Define a new environment for LibreTexts-style math
\tcbset{
    libretext/.style={
        enhanced,
        sharp corners,
        attach boxed title to top left={yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight},
        colframe=#1!30!black,
        colback=#1!20,
        colbacktitle=#1!30!black,
        toprule=0pt, rightrule=0pt, bottomrule=0pt,
        coltitle=white,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        boxed title style={sharp corners}
    }
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=section]{example}[1][]{
    libretext=blue,
    title={\faCheck~Example~\thetcbcounter},
    #1,
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=section]{exercise}[1][]{
    libretext=blue,
    title={\faQuestion~Exercise~\thetcbcounter},
    #1,
}

\newtcolorbox{caution}[1][]{
    libretext=red,
    title={\faHandPaperO~Caution},
    #1,
}

\newtcolorbox{note}[1][]{
    libretext=gray,
    title={\faThumbTack~Note},
    #1,
}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}{
    libretext=green,
    before title={\faCubes~}
}{th}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within=section]{definition}{Definition}{
    libretext=green,
    before title={\faPencil~}
}{df}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
    
\begin{theorem}{}{}
        Solve the equation for $x$:
        \[ ax^2 + bx + c = 0 \]
\end{theorem}

\begin{example}
        Solve the equation for $x$:
        \[ ax^2 + bx + c = 0 \]
\end{example}

\begin{definition}{Relative Frequency}{}
        Solve the equation for $x$:
        \[ ax^2 + bx + c = 0 \]
\end{definition}

\begin{caution}
        Solve the equation for $x$:
        \[ ax^2 + bx + c = 0 \]
\end{caution}  

\begin{note}
        Solve the equation for $x$:
        \[ ax^2 + bx + c = 0 \]
\end{note}

\begin{exercise}
        Solve the equation for $x$:
        \[ ax^2 + bx + c = 0 \]
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Before the optional title "some title", how to get the name "Theorem" with numbering following the sections. I got a few errors using ``\newtcbtheorem``.

Comment: Now, the code works fine with ``\newtcbtheorem`` instead of ``\newtcolorbox``. But I must use the theorem environment with two ``{ }``.     e.g.,                                        
         ``\begin{mythm}{some title}{ }                                                                             
            text....                                                                                                 
          \end{mythm}``.                                                                                                      
  Can I make the ``{some title } { }`` optional?

Comment: @Litun A `\newtheorem` environment always has two mandatory parameters. They can be empty  but you have to include the brackets: `\begin{theorem}{}{}`. By the way I've updated the answer with all other definitions.

Comment: I copied and pasted the earlier code for each environment, taking up much space. The updated code is the optimal one and best for my case. **Is there a way to make a print option wherein the colored environments will be removed except for their text in black?** By this, the printout will save a lot of ink.